# Display a list of all Azure Web Apps Custom Domain from Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-cloud-shell

I am able to get the complete list of appservice URLs like something.azurewebsites.net but nothing found on the web to list custom domains of all azure webapps. How can I get a list of custom domains for all azure webapps from Azure CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- ***To get the custom domains for all the web apps in the Subscription***

```cs
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp
$hostName = $webApp.HostNames 
# or get all enabled hostnames using $hostName = $webApp.enabledHostNames 
Write-Host $hostName
```

[image]

- ***To get the custom domains  in the selected Resource Group***

```cs
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName YourResourceGroupName 
$hostName = $webApp.HostNames
Write-Host $hostName
```

[image]

- ***To get the custom domains for the selected web apps***

```cs
$webApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName YourResourceGroupName -Name WebAppName
$hostName = $webApp.HostNames
Write-Host $hostName
```

[image]